# Mongoose sample operator not working

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Whenever I remove the line with sample with only match remaining, the code works fine, but when I add it back like this:

```
Model.aggregate(
    {$match: {}},
    {$sample: {size: 2}},
    (err, rsp)=>{
   callback(err,rsp);
});
```

It throws an error saying the first argument must be a string or buffer. It can only be caused by {$sample: {size: 2}}. Why is it?
Is sample not working in mongoose??

Comment: which mongoose version you are using?
I am using ^4.11.8 and its working fine

Comment: @AyushMittal Im using 4.10.8

Comment: can u share the screenshot of the error

Comment: @AyushMittal I added it in edit. This error happens when I {$sample: {size:2}} back. Everything runs smoothly when only match is used. m_resume.js:94 is callback(err,rsp) in the snippet.

Comment: Works fine when I try it. What version of MongoDB server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
model.instance.aggregate([{ $match:  buildQuery(model) }]).sample(20).exec(function (err, results) {
    console.log(model.size, results.length);
});
```